# I want to multiply 2 columns and add the result to the next row of first column

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in my SQL DBA i.e a and b and rownumber.Now my requirement is that I want to calculate a*b for rownumber =1 and the result will be populated in a column of rownumber =2 and the calculation goes on without using loop.
Kindly help as I am stuck from past 2 hours

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which DB (Version Info also required) are you using? You may be able to use `LEAD` and `LAG` functions.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as well as an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the response.I am using SQL 2012

Comment: There are 3 columns in the db column a,column b and rownumber as column C.I want to multiply a and b for row 1(suppose the value of column a is 2 and column b is 1 for row =1) then a*b i.e 2*1=2 should be the value of column a for row =2.

Comment: Shreya, to use this site you should: 1) Use the [edit] link to add information directly to the question, rather than in a comment and 2) to answer someone in comments precede their user name with a @, for example @JonathanWillcock - otherwise there will be no notification. Stack Overflow is not a "forum". You might also want to read the usage guidelines in the [help].

Comment: @ShreyaSingh: can you post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this....

```
   ; with cte as ( select a*b as res, row_number + 1 as Rownumber from table)
   select t.a, t.b, c.res, t.rownumber from table as t inner join cte as c on t.rownumber=c.rownumber
```

Here you have all 3 columns and you are free to use any record with respect to any combination.

Answer (score 0):

The most general thing to do here (but not optimal, depending on the query engine / SQL version you are using) would be to calculate a*b and then JOIN the result against the original table, mapping rownumber to rownumber-1.

Comment: Ya but that would not be optimal solution.Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL Server 2012, you will be able to use the convenient `LEAD` OR `LAG` functions.  `LEAD` gets the value of the following row, whilst `LAG` gets the previous row.

As an example, take a look at:

```
declare @demo table (a int, b int, rownumber int)

insert into @demo VALUES
(2, 1, 1),
(4, 6, 2),
(4, 3, 3),
(5, 6, 4),
(2, 3, 5)

SELECT LAG(a * b) over(order by rownumber) as col1, rownumber
FROM @demo
```

Results:

```
col1    rownumber
NULL    1
2       2
24      3
12      4
30      5
```

You will be able to paste this into a new query window in SSMS and run it.  Note that the first result gives NULL.  This is to be expected as there is no previous row.  You can use `COALESCE` (or in T-SQL `ISNULL`) to get rid of this, if you wish.

Please note for future SQL questions, what I have done here: I have provided a SQL statement that creates a table, with the correct columns, and also an insert statement to add sample data.  In future please do this yourself, as it saves the time of the volunteers here. All you should then add in addition, is some sample results.

Comment: Lag won't work here as we don't have column A populated already.It is a derived column basis the calculation of the first row

Comment: Then please edit your question supplying sample data, and sample results in the form I have shown.  Otherwise we really cannot help you.